# Why would the for loop on an array in java not initializing

Tags: java, arrays

There are two four loops on my homework problem but while running the code the final for loop is not initializing at all for the desired iteration.

```
public class Arrays {
     /** 
     Reads in 5 scores and show how much each 
     Score differs from the higher score
     */
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double [] score = new double[5];
        int index;
        double max;
    
        System.out.println("Enter " + score.length + " scores:");
        score[0] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        max = score[0];
        for (index = 1;index < score.length;index ++)
        {
            score[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if (score[index] > max)
                max = score[index];
        }
    
        System.out.println("The new max is " + max);
        System.out.println("The scores are:");
        for (index = 0;index > score.length;index++)
            System.out.println(score[index] + " differs the max by " + (max - score[index]));
    }

}
```

Output received:

```
Enter 5 scores:
10
10.5
11
11.5
12.5
The new max is 12.5
The scores are:
```

Desired Output:

```
Enter 5 scores:
10
10.5
11
11.5
12.5
The new max is 12.5
The scores are:
10 differs the max by 2.5
10.5 differs the max by 2.0
11 differs the max by 1.5
11.5 differs the max by 1.0
12.5 differs the max by 0.0
```

Comment: The condition (`index > score.length`) will never evaluate to true.

Comment: will work if `score.length` is smaller then -1 xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is not being cycled because the condition `index > score.length` is always `false`. You are initializing `index` with a value of `0` and then checking if it's value is greater then the size of your `score` array which in this situation is `5`. Invert your condition to a logically sound evaluation like so and the loop will run as expected:

```
for (index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
    System.out.println(score[index] + " differs the max by " + (max - score[index]));
```